# Use a property in a constructor of an object fails

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, constructor

I have a class defined like this:

```
class TouchScreenDisabledGrid:DataGrid,INotifyPropertyChanged
```

I want to change soome of my class behaviour depanding on it's properties, that are set threw the xaml when using it in a window.

For example the following:

```
<my:TouchScreenDisabledGrid x:Name="dataGridView" Tag="13"  />
```

Will cause an exception if In my constructor I try to check this value:

```
    public TouchScreenDisabledGrid(){
            Console.WriteLine(this.Tag.ToString());
    }
```

Why is that and how can I check the propery and use it?

Comment: What is the kind of exception you get? What does the message say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects defined in XAML are constructed using the *default constructor* and *then* their properties are set. So imagine that this:

```
<my:TouchScreenDisabledGrid x:Name="dataGridView" Tag="13"  />
```

Is the moral equivalent of this:

```
var g = new TouchScreenDisabledGrid();
g.Name = "dataGridView";
g.Tag = "13";
```

It should now be obvious why `Tag` is `null` inside your constructor, hence you are getting a `NullReferenceException` when you call `ToString()`.

Continuing further, you cannot use the classical model of doing something inside the constructor that depends on object properties being set. You have to find another way of achieving your goal -- what way, depends on what exactly the goal is (for example you can use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to detect that a property has been set; or you can listen to an event that triggers later in the lifetime of the visual and fetch the values from there).

Comment: I understand your explanasion. For the description of "tag" it is used to pass information about the object. I want to save it and check it for later to determine some path in program. Would it be smarter to check it every time I want to use it? Is there a more efficeint way?

Comment: @meyou: It would certainly be more correct to check it every time you want to use it (just like any other property actually).

Comment: Yeah but every time i need a try catch thing, so if it is not filled i would use a default. It maked duplication in alot of functions. Never mind ill use a function that will return it everytime

Answer (score 2):

If the property is set in XAML it will not be set in the constructor. Use OnLoaded override to do this.

Comment: It does not have this property(OnLoaded) that I can override. How can I get to that?